# MYSQL Column addition based on a condition in another Column

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to add a column to the query o/p based on a condition in another column. There is a column for Enrollment_Status, if the value is 'Cancelled' or' Dis enrolled', then the new column should have a concatenated value.

I have written a query for this , but the o/p is not correct. I have tried to write a CASE WHEN query, but it is giving me an error that - "Sub-query is returning multiple rows". I am currently using an 'IF' condition for the same.
The name of the table is 'sbi' in the database.
The o/p should be the concatenation of multiple columns and one of them should have a minimum value which is a date field.

```
IF((sbi.enrollment_status='Cancelled' OR sbi.enrollment_status='Disenrolled'), CONCAT(HCID, enrollment_status, created_at) IN (SELECT 
            CONCAT(hcid, enrollment_status, MIN(created_at))
            FROM
                sbi
                    WHERE sbi.enrollment_status='Cancelled' OR sbi.enrollment_status='Disenrolled'
                    Group By hcid),
            '--') AS 'Disenroll Date'
```

The expected o/p is '000M99920Cancelled2019-08-28 00:00:00'
But currently the query is generating a '0' for the same.
Attached is the image for the o/p that I have received[image]

Comment: Where do `000M99920` and `2019-08-28 00:00:00` come from? They cannot be seen in your image. Also, please provide sample data and expected results as tabular text (not images) so we can use it to test the query...

Comment: @GMB: the sample o/p fir the highlighted yellow in the image should be :
'241M53883Cancelled2019-05-19 00:00:00'